# How can I prove $a$ had infinite order $\Rightarrow$ $f(a)$ has infinite order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Problem:** Let $f : G → H$ be an isomorphism. Prove that if $a \in G$
>   has infinite order, then so does $f(a)$, and if $a$ has finite order
>   $n$, then so does $f(a)$. Conclude that if $G$ has an element of some
>   order $n$ and $H$ does not, then $G \not\cong H$.

**My proof:** If $a$ has finite order $n$, then $a^n=e \Rightarrow f(a^n) = f(a)^n = e$. So, $f(a)$ has order $n$.

How can I prove $a$ had infinite order $\Rightarrow$ $f(a)$ has infinite order?

Comment: Have you considered the contrapositive statement?

Comment: I know the contrapositive statement, but I couldn't describe it on my proof.

Comment: The contrapositive statement give $f(a).f(a) \dots \neq e$

Comment: Since $f$ is an isomorphism, can't you use $f^{-1}$ combined with the thing you already showed?  That should give you the contrapositive unless I glossed over something.

Comment: Just because $(f(a))^{n}=e$ does not mean that the order of $f(a)$ is n. You need to further prove that $n$ is the least positive integer which does the above.

Comment: Suppose $a$ has infinite order and $f(a)$ has finite order $n$. We have $f(a)^n = e$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(a^n) = e$ $\Rightarrow$ $a^n = e$, contract with hypothesis. Is that right?

Comment: If $f$ is an isomorphism, then $f^{-1}$ is also an isomorphism.

Comment: @AshishK Are we need to prove $n$ is the least positive integer with $f(a)^n = e$?

Comment: @Minh yes consider if $m$ is an positive integer with $m<n$ such that $(f(x))^{m}=e$, can you obtain a contradiction here?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof works in the other direction as well:
$$
e = f(a)^n = f(a^n) \overset{f \text{ isomorphism}}{\implies} e = f^{-1}(e) = a^n
$$